# Height and Width of tableViewCell changes on scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I am working on a socket base chat module. I am using 5 different custom cells in a single tableView for different purposes. When I scroll tableView it changes layouts, width, and height of certain cells. please help me out. I have gone through too many StackOverflow's questions but my problem is not getting solved.

Comment: You have to show the code you have written. Nobody can ***guess*** what you are doing. Please review [ask].

Comment: I have solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an extension for rounding corners of my cell. that extension was causing the problem.  I was using the following extension.

```
    extension UIView {
   func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

to solve my problem i used following code in my tableViewCell

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.chatTextView.clipsToBounds = true
              chatTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        chatTextView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

        //set the cell to initial state here
        //set like the button to initial state - title, font, color, etc.
    }

}
```

now my cells are working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set automatic row height or width on storyboard unclick it, maybe it changes the layout.
In the view controller you can set height like this;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {}
```